# Eliminating sweet scented paint smell?

Tags: paint

We just bought a home with a mother-in-law suite.  The suite has an overpowering sweet scent like commercial air freshener.

I've checked every outlet and switch, and conclude they must have added a scented product to the high gloss wall and ceiling paint.
I'd hate to paint it, then find the scent bleeds through the new paint.

It's disgustingly sweet.  Options? Interior sandblasting?  Chemical wash?

Comment: @AlaskaMan  LOL, but that's a mean comment! To the OP's issue.  Does the room have carpeting? if so, the smell might be coming from a cleaning agent used to clean it and there are "leftovers".

Comment: If carpeted, removing that (or cleaning it with a less-odiferous product) may also help. I would lean towards removal if the prior owners felt the need to clean with a highly odiferous product, as that may indicate cleaning up some horrible stuff...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: I'm confused by the fact that you "checked every outlet and switch" and that lead you to believe the paint is scented. That's an... odd... leap of logic... That said, how long ago was it painted? The odor may go away on its own within a week or two.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to rent an ozone generator, or hire an odor remediation contractor with one. Those are used to nullify various odors by generating highly reactive ozone (O3 rather than O2) which aggressively oxidizes whatever it encounters before naturally decaying (if it can't find anything else to react with, 2 O3 can get together to make 3 O2.)

Ozone is not healthy for people to breathe, so follow all safety precautions if using an ozone generator, but they are a highly effective way of neutralizing odors.